# jquery.placepicker.js Как сделать чтобы при вводе кириллицей названия города, выпадал список городов только латиницей

Tags: google-maps-api, google-places-api

Как сделать чтобы при вводе кириллицей названия города, выпадал список городов только латиницей

```
<input type="text" id="autocomplete"/>

<script>
  var input = document.getElementById('autocomplete');
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
</script>
```

Comment: обрабатывать нажатие клавиши , брать кириллический символ и находя ему пару в латинском символе отображать список по выборке латинских букв .
Создать массив из парных символов , кириллица - латиница 
или два массива кириллица и латиница .
По коду получили символ , если он кириллический - нашли его пару , и по парному латинскому символу вывели список городов

Comment: вот здесь https://learn.javascript.ru/keyboard-events все есть , получает и кириллицу и латиницу